# how to redirect from a jsf facelet if an el expression is true?

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6, el

I have a jsf facelet which displays a summary of a search process.
Now I want to redirect to a detail page, if only one element was found by the search engine. I do not want to implement this redirect in my beans because I want to have the "knowledge" about this redirection out of my java code.

So I want to write something like that:

```xml
<ui:redirect if="#{searchResult.count eq 1}" target="details.jsf">
   <f:param name="id" value="#{searchResult.firstResult.technicalId}" />
</ui:redirect>
```

Any solutions or ideas for that?

I know, there are page-actions in JSF 2.2 but I am using JEE6 and there is JSF 2.0 available.
Btw. I currently I am usingMyFaces, Primefaces and Richfaces.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this job in the controller, not in the view.

To get search results, you first need to invoke an action method by a search form, right? Just do the redirect job right there. You can tell JSF to send a redirect by specifying the `faces-redirect=true` in the query string of the action outcome.

```
public String search() {
    results = service.find(query);

    if (results.size() == 1) {
        return "details?faces-redirect=true&id=" + results.get(0).getTechnicalId();
    }
    else {
        return "results";
    }
}
```

Or if it's a GET request which is handled by `<f:event type="preRenderView">`, then do so:

```
public void onPreRenderViewListener() {
    results = service.find(query);

    if (results.size() == 1) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("details.jsf?id=" + results.get(0).getTechnicalId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the cleanest way is to generate the action in the bean.
Anyway I would propose you to simulate a click in case your search count is eq to 1 with javascript.

you need an input hidden containing the count:

```
<h:inputHidden id="count" value="#{searchResult.count}" />
```

and a hidden button to trigger the redirection:

```
<h:commandButton id="redirectButton" action="details.jsf" style="display: none;" />
```

then when you trigger the search, you update the input count and oncomplete you can check
if the value of count is 1, then you can do a click on the commandButton.

If you use Jquery, it would be something like

```
    if($("#count").val()==1){
        $("#redirectButton").click();
    }
```